# Adding another attribute to a class with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If I have a class like this:

```
class="thing-1"
```

I want to add:

```
class="thing-1 thing-2"
```

How can I do this using jQuery?

Comment: `$('.thing-1').addClass("thing-2")`

Comment: Please before asking question google ur need first..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also add mulitple classes try this:-

```
$('.thing-1').addClass('thing-1 thing-2 thing-3');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use .addClass : [Source](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)

```
$('.thing-1').addClass('thing-2')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
.addClass('thing-2')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.thing-1').addClass('thing-2')
```

reference **[addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)**